# Through axle came apart, can't put it back together

Tags: maintenance, through-axle

When pulling the axle out after disengaging the quick connect, the shaft won't push through and the other side all the little metal pieces fell out.

Tire won't come out and cannot put it back together. Now what?

Brand is "Suntour Q-Loc axle"

[image: Photograph looking down on the hub of the front wheel showing the partially removed through axle]

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit better.  Is the photo of how the axle is now, or have you removed the axle from the bike. When you say "fell out", are the on the ground loose, or is the photo showing what they are like now?

Comment: I tend to think that there's a manipulation error. Did you get an instructions booklet with your bike?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you just opened the lever as looks from your answer now, you may need to unscrew it additionaly, try to rotate the bottom side (as in the photo) "knob". Do not overtry however as the core will come out. Otherwise pull the lever out on another side. With a little bit more force these metal segments that are now spread should come together and pass through the hole in the fork.

Comment: The metal segments need space between the frame and end cap to 'collapse'.   Pulling the end cap lightly while wriggling it around helps.  There is a knack once you 'get it' is easy.